# problem running rosjava_tutorial_pubsub

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was following the tutorial in [rosjava_core](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html), all went smoothly untill I tried to excute the example in rosjava_tutorial_pubsub, in fact, it said in [excuting nodes](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/getting_started.html#executing-nodes) to do

```
roscore & ./build/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker & ./build/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub  org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Listener
```

First, ./rosjava_tutorial_pubsub dosen't exist in this directory but in build/scripts/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub. Second, when trying

```
./build/scripts/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker
```

I got this Error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ros/RosRun
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ros.RosRun
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: org.ros.RosRun. Program will exit.

Anyone got this tutorial to work, since gradle ?

Thanks for help,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34092/problem-running-rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/) by [Anas](https://answers.ros.org/users/736/anas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2012-05-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on 2012-05-16**:
The same issue here. By the way it seems that only rosjava_tutorial_pubsub is build, not the tutorial_services.

**Comment by [Gaëtan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1463/ga%C3%ABtan/) on 2012-05-16**:
same problem too ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to run the sample applications. The
Tutorial is a bit wrong about the path. Here is how it starts. Make sure you have called gradle installApp in the folder of the tutorial. This will create a folder install in the build folder. THe correct call to the application is

```
    ./rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/build/install/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_torial_pubsub org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker
```

The same holds for the other tutorials and for self generated apps.

---

Originally posted by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) with karma: 202 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anas](https://answers.ros.org/users/736/anas/) on 2012-05-22**:
thanks it's working

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
this is not an answer but I try to solve the same problem.

Here is where I am :

I add in the script : ./build/scripts/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub
direct links to the class path :
CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/lib...:...:...:/home/gseverac/Documents/ROS/my_workspaceNewROSJava/rosjava_core/rosjava/bin:/home/gseverac/Documents/ROS/my_workspaceNewROSJava/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/bin:/usr/share/java

then the program find RosRun.class and RosRuntimeException.class

but now it is looking for com/google/common/collect/Lists :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists

and I'm stuck there ...

any ideas ? It seams to have a main problem with classpath definition but I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks

Gaëtan

---

Originally posted by [Gaëtan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1463/ga%C3%ABtan/) with karma: 56 on 2012-05-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on 2012-05-21**:
I found out that the generated script "rosjava_tutorial_pub" sets APP_HOME="pwd -P`" and than sets all the classpath to APP_HOME/lib/..... How I understood the build system, all libs are generated in the maven repository, e.g. ~/.m2/repository. Shouldn't the Classpath point to the maven repository?